# How to use AWS Comprehend use node js from lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying use AWS comprehend from Lambda,My Lambda already have ComprehendFullAccess Role.
This code is as follow.

Why the return data is null?

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const comprehend = new AWS.Comprehend();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let params = {
      LanguageCode: 'en',
      Text:'Hello from Tim'
    }
    
    comprehend.detectEntities(params, function (err, data) {
      if(err){
        return null
      }else{
        return data
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `await` in an async method.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let params = {
      LanguageCode: 'en',
      Text:'Hello from Tim'
    }
    
    return comprehend.detectEntities(params).promise();
};
```